# How to remove commas from strings in an array?

Tags: javascript, csv

I need to remove commas which are in an array of odata objects. Each item has a `description` which sometimes contains commas. I need to remove those commas.
Here is what I've attempted:
Parent Component:

```
  <CSVComponent capxs={allCaps} />
```

Child Component:

```
import { CSVLink } from "react-csv";

export interface ICSVComponentProps {
    capxs: IListItem[];
}

export const CSVComponent: React.FunctionComponent<ICSVComponentProps> = (props: ICSVComponentProps) => {
    const [results, setResults] = React.useState([]);
   
    const headers = [
        { label: "Id", key: "id" },
        { label: "Title", key: "title" },
        { label: "Description", key: "description" },
    ];
 const getCaps = (c: IListItem[]) => {
        const results = [];
        for (let i = 0; i <= c.length - 1; i++) {
            results[i] = {
                id: props.capxs[i].Id,
                title: props.capxs[i].Title,
                description: props.capxs[i].Description.replace(",",""),
            };
        }
        setResults(results);
    };

    return (
        <DefaultButton className={styles.csvButton}
        onClick={() => getCaps(props.capxs)}
        >
            <CSVLink data={results} headers={headers}>
                Create CSV
            </CSVLink>
        </DefaultButton>
    );
```

Update:
I've updated the code sample above with the Parent component props pass down and more of the child component.
Here is an image showing the array that is created and stored in state. This state is then used by react-csv:

[image]

The `description` value in each item in the array has the comma removed, but react-csv seems to ignore this and it detects the commas, therefore creating incorrect columns in the produced csv file.

Comment: Please show example array

Comment: It's not clear when you're getting the objects. Are the objects the result of the react-csv step? There should be a way to configure react-csv to ignore commas in certain fields (by designating that field a "text" field or something similar).

Comment: *"This works to remove the commas"* - If the code already successfully removes commas, why are you asking how to remove commas?  *"but it's too late for react-csv"* - The code shown doesn't appear to include that at all.  So is the problem with removing commas from strings, or is the problem with your React component(s)?  *"I need [it] to happen at the start of the function above not during the for"* - What does that even mean?  You want to execute the `for` loop before declaring the `results` variable?  This description of the problem doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you need

```
const memoizedCaps = useMemo<IListItem[]>(() => {
    return caps.map(el => ({ ...el, description: el.description.replace(',', '') }));
}, [caps]);

const getCaps = () => {
    setResults(memoizedCaps);
};
```

Comment: sorry this hasn't worked, I spoke to soon.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved by using:

```
 const getCaps = (caps: IListItem[]) => {
        const results = [];
        for (let i = 0; i <= caps.length - 1; i++) {
            results[i] = {
                description: props.capxs[i].Description.replace(/,/g, '""'),
            };
        }
        setResults(results);
    };
```

Not ideal but it's a limitation of react-csv.
Ref: https://github.com/react-csv/react-csv/issues/176

Thanks for all your help.